# Coordinates of Point after 90 Degree Rotation about centre of Circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

I know of a method that involves drawing two right angled triangles and using trigonometry to find the answer. This is quite a lengthy method. Is there a method that uses less than a minute to solve this question?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Some test that you wrote recently?  So many questions.

Comment: @A.G could you please elaborate?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN Yes. Do you know how I could solve this in under a minute?

Comment: Maybe you could prove the y coordinate is negative.

Comment: Using the trigonometric method you already know you can easily evaluate $\Delta x'=\Delta y$ and $\Delta y'=-\Delta x$. 
You can remember this as a rule or you can try to rotate the triangle you've drawn for the evaluation of the deltas.
Obviously it can be simplified only for specific angles as 90 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rotating vector $$\vec{v} = (x,y)$$ 90° clockwise (in a right-handed coordinate system) yields $$\vec{v}' = (y, -x)$$

Here, you have center $$\vec{c} = (2,3)$$ and point $$\vec{p} = (6,6)$$

The vector that rotates is $$\vec{r} = \vec{p} - \vec{c} = (4,3)$$ Rotating it 90° clockwise yields $$\vec{r}' = (3, -4)$$

The rotated point is then $$\vec{p}' = \vec{c} + \vec{r}' = (5, -1)$$

(In a right-handed coordinate system, the more common rotation is counterclockwise; then, $\vec{v}' = (-y, x)$.)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the vector from the center to P. Then you calculate the perpendicular vector (to do this you just need to change the coordinates and multiply one of them by (-1)) and "add" it to the center. (you just need to be sure if you need to add or subtract, anyway, under a minute)

Answer (score 1):

We will show that the point lies below the X- Axis. ( There is only one option with negative ordinate).

Both points of the circle on the X-Axis is given in the graph, (6,0) and (-2,0). The distance of these points from P is 6 and 10 respectively . But by Pythagoras, the distance between P and its image is $5 \sqrt2$ and $10 > 5 \sqrt2 > 6$. So, by figure, the point lies below the X Axis.

Answer (score 1):

If we are allowed to use complex numbers, then letting $(x,y)$ be the point we want, we have 
$$(6+6i)-(2+3i)=i((x+yi)-(2+3i)),$$
i.e.
$$4+3i=(-y+3)+i(x-2)$$
giving $x=5,y=-1$.